# How do I declare a composite interface in Go?

Tags: interface, go

The following interface defines a set of methods to be implemented by mooing objects:

```
type Mooing interface {
    Moo() string
}
```

The following defines a set of methods to be implemented by grazing objects:

```
type Grazing interface {
    EatGrass()
}
```

I have a function that operates on cows:

```
func Milk(cow *Cow)
```

It doesn't have to be a cow, though--anything that conforms to `Mooing` and `Grazing` is close enough. In Go, is it possible to specify a parameter of `Mooing and Grazing`? In pseudocode, something like the following?

```
func Milk(cow {Mooing, Grazing})
```

In other words, only parameters that satisfy both of these interfaces will be accepted.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can compose interfaces in Go as follows:

```
type MooingAndGrazing interface {
    Mooing
    Grazing
}
```

If you don't want to declare a new named type, you could inline this as:

```
func Milk(cow interface{Mooing; Grazing})
```

You can experiment with this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/xAODkd85Zq

Comment: +1 This answer and the question itself make me want to try Go.

Comment: Beautiful. And only one character away from what I thought it should look like! I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.